# ANSYS 17.1 Mechanical APDL runing error

Tags: 16.04

I installed ANSYS 17.1 succesfully. But when i try to run Mechanical APDL i get an error:

```
.../ANSYS17.1/ansys_inc/v171/ansys/bin/linux64/ansys.e: error while loading shared libraries: libXm.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Looks like you need `libmotif-dev` installed from the repositories.

Comment: I installed libmotif-dev than i get an error:

..../ANSYS17.1/ansys_inc/v171/ansys/bin/linux64/ansys.e: error while loading shared libraries: libXm.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in Ansys Mechanical 2023R2 running on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. The solution for me was this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libxm4
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with ANSYS Mechanical v17.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and resolved it by finding the missing libraries elsewhere on the system (you can try `locate`) and creating symbolic links (try `sudo ln -s`) of them in ansys_inc/v172/ansys/lib/linx64 and ansys_inc/v172/ansys/syslib/linx64. It appears that most of the missing libraries can be found in ansys_inc/v172/, but in the directories of other products such as CFD-Post and CFX. Make sure that the name of the symbolic link matches the files ANSYS looks for exactly, and is for the correct architecture (usually 64-bit).

To give you an example, ANSYS Mechanical also reported a problem of missing libjpeg.so.62. I linked the newer libjpeg.so.9.2.0 from the OS to resolve it, as follows:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.9.2.0 /usr/local/ansys_inc/v172/ansys/syslib/linx64/libjpeg.so.62
```